# How to fill remaining polar area with color

Tags: chart.js

I'm drawing a polar area with chart.js to show progress in a category.
How can I fill out the remaining area with a different color/opacity?

[image: example polar area]

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: I got the desired result by adding another dataset with the same backgroundColor, but changed the opacity.